# Uploaded image is not showing in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the below html for image.

```html
<span class="CaptureViewer-imageWrapper">    
  <div class="EnlargedPreview-container">
    <div 
      tabindex="-1" 
      aria-label="Photo of your document" 
      aria-live="off" 
      aria-expanded="false" role="img"
    ></div>
            
    <button 
      aria-labelledby="preview-button-label" 
      class="EnlargedPreview-button EnlargedPreview-button-overlay"
    >
      <span 
        id="preview-button-label" 
        class="EnlargedPreview-button-text"
      >Enlarge image</span>
    </button>
  </div>
    
  <img 
    class="CaptureViewer-image" 
    src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA" 
    alt="Photo of your document" 
    aria-hidden="true">
</span>
```

I have tried uploading the image and checked in the desktop browser using mobile mode and the image is displaying. But the image is not getting displayed in the actual mobile browser.
I have checked the image src url. The url length is very large and it is having 440446 characters. And the size is 431 kb.

I  tried giving srcset for the image as below.

```js
var imagesource = $(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("src");

$(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("srcset",imagesource+ "300W");
$(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("srcset",imagesource+ "600W");
$(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("srcset",imagesource+ "900W");
```

I checked the width of the screen in the desktop using mobile mode and tried giving the pixel width as below.

```
$(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("srcset",imagesource+ "414px");
```

But when i tried above codes, the image is not displayed even in the desktop browser and the below screen is displayed.

[image]

The above screen is displayed in the mobile browser also after image upload.

Kindly advise how to fix this issue.
I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Use inspect element on the webpage and see how the image tag looks like, the problem should be obvious if you're setting the source incorrectly

Comment: image tag must have src attribute so try $(".CaptureViewer-image").attr('src',imagesource).css('width','414')

Comment: Hi Satinder singh, tried the above code but it is not working.